# Can HTTPS Nodejs read .crt?

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am trying to create https server like this

```
https
.createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync(key),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(cert),
      ca: fs.readFileSync(ca)
    },
    webServer
  )
  .listen(webServerPort, function () {
    console.log("Server Monitor Web Service Running on port: " + webServerPort);
  });
```

However at cert: I'm receiving an error saying

```
node:internal/tls/secure-context:65
context.setCert(cert);
Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

The cert is referencing to a .crt file

Can HTTPS create servers from .crt?

Is this error thrown because the cert itself is invalid or because of the file extension type?

Thanks

Comment: Can you open the file in notepad? If not you may have to convert a binary file to PEM using `openssl x509 -inform DER -in <file.crt> -out <file.pem>`. On *Nix use `file <file.crt>` to find out the file type or use `less` if you're feeling brave.

Comment: I get:

unable to load certificate
8812602624:error:0DFFF0A8:asn1 encoding routines: